# Can't compare date

Tags: android

I am fetching certain data from JSON. I have a date `("PaymentDueDateFormatted")` which I need to be compared with the current Date and display the data in listviews. But I can't establish this. This shows zero data.

I am getting the date as for eg: `"22-Dec-2017"`. Is it to be converted into millies for compare?

```
ArrayList<String[]> invoiceListData1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<invoices.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = invoices.getJSONObject(i);
    String date1 = jsonObject1.getString("PaymentDueDateFormatted");
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (currentDate.after(date1)) {
        String[] data = new String[9];
        data[0] = jsonObject1.getString("ID");
        data[1] = jsonObject1.getString("InvoiceNo");
        switch (getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Common.CUSTOMER_OR_SUPPLIER)) {
            case Common.CUSTOMER:
                data[2] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("customerObj").getString("ID");
                data[3] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("customerObj").getString("ContactPerson");
                data[7] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("companiesObj").getString("Name");
                break;
            case Common.SUPPLIER:
                data[2] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("suppliersObj").getString("ID");
                data[3] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("suppliersObj").getString("ContactPerson");
                data[7] = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("companiesObj").getString("Name");
                break;
        }
        data[4] = jsonObject1.getString("PaymentDueDateFormatted");
        data[5] = jsonObject1.getString("BalanceDue");
        data[6] = jsonObject1.getString("PaidAmount");
        data[8] = jsonObject1.getString("DueDays");
        invoiceListData1.add(data);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Invoices.this, invoiceListData1, (getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Common.CUSTOMER_OR_SUPPLIER) == Common.CUSTOMER ? Common.SALESLIST : Common.PURCHASELIST));
        invoiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
        (findViewById(R.id.list_card)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this :

```
String date1 = jsonObject1.getString("PaymentDueDateFormatted");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(date1));// Create calender variable from date and the compare with current time

Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
if ( currentDate.after(cal)) {
  }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to print your `currentdate` and you will understand why both dates are not equal.

> don't convert into millies bcoz in current date millies are included
>   time like hours, minutes and seconds

```
 Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

> this will give you time in including everything(seconds, minutes, hours and more ) so it never be same as string you getting from the response

try this

```
Date date = new Date();
String todayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(date);
```

instead of this

```
 Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and compare with your string date with it

Comment: Bro my string date is in th format 22-Dec-2017 not in 22-12-2017. Will that be a problem?

Comment: use MMM instead of MM

Comment: Bro can you tell me how to compare it?  Right now iam doing" if ( todayDate.after(date1))". But it shows error

Comment: where is your compare method ?

Comment: The if statement

Comment: where is your after method ? look on edit answer and undersatnd that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177697/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-androdevil).

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(date1);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        date.before(cal.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both dates in milliseconds and compare them:

```
String string = "22-Dec-2017";

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Date date = null;
try {
    date = format.parse(string);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (date != null) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    Long dateInMils = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Calendar calToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    calToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calToday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Long todayInMils = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    if (dateInMils < todayInMils) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```